# Issues debugging a release version of app

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, release

In a MSVC 2019 64-bit app the debug version compiles and runs well, but the release version throws an exception from within a statically linked library.
I do have the source code for the library, but have not figured out how to get debug symbols for it so that I can step through the code to track down the issue.
I do know how to set the debug information for the EXE in the linker properties, but have no idea what options to set for the library so that the library symbols will become available withing the IDE

Comment: You'll need to either get the symbols if they are available somewhere, or otherwise rebuild the library from sources with debug information enabled.

Comment: I do have the source, but don't know how to rebuild the library to produce the symbols. When I link the whole lot together, I get a number of:error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL': value

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Issues were in the original source code. Adaptations needed for 64-bit version